# PHP rquire_once from root

Tags: php, include, root, require-once

*Firs of im pretty new in PHP.*

I want to include a php file from root in another php file like this.

```
require_once "/getPublisher.php?id=' . $xy;
```

The file where i type this code is in '/page/page.php'.

```
--------------- ROOT -----------------
    -page
       -> page.php----------------
                                 - trying to require_once '/getPublisher.php'
                                 - into '/page/page.php'
    -getPublisher.php-------------
```

I am getting these error codes back.

> Warning: require_once(/users/uplade/www/getPublisher.php?id=123)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /users/uplade/www/page/page.php on line 83

and

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/users/uplade/www/getPublisher.php?id=123'
>   (include_path='.') in /users/uplade/www/page/page.php on
>   line 83

So how to include root files in non-root files?

EDIT:

> Warning: require_once(/getPublisher.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /users/uplade/www/page/page.php on line 84

WHAT IM DOING WRONG.

**SOLUTION:**
I removed the slash require_once 'getPublisher.php'; Thats way it worked for me!

Comment: Is your file located at /users/uplade/www/getPublisher.php?

Comment: include/require files by filesystem path, not web path; and your'e including a file by name, nut as a url, so don't pass args in that way

Comment: @Webomatik yes it is. Removed all params, still gives same error as before.

Comment: You're including a file in `/users/uplade/www` from a file in `/users/uplade/www/page`, so perhaps `require_once "../getPublisher.php";` rather than using an absolute filesystem reference from the filesystem root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters on require(). Try removing it:

```
require_once "/getPublisher.php";
```

Comment: Your file has an uppercase "P", is that the case?

Comment: Ok, so it should be require_once "/users/uplade/www/getPublisher.php";

Comment: require starts at the root of your server, not the web root.

Comment: checked the name 100 times. Yes the P is there.

Comment: looooooool, i removed the slash and it worked *argh* ! Im so anoyed but also happy.

Answer (score 0):

With `require_once "/getPublisher.php";` you are trying to include a file from the filesystem root, not from the document root.

If the files would be in the same directory, you would include it like this:
`require_once "getPublisher.php";`

But in your case, it's one level up, so just include it like this:
`require_once "../getPublisher.php";`

Answer (score 0):

`reuire` and `include` (and their `_once` variants) locate a file on the filesystem based on its absolute path, falling back to a configurable set of include paths (used for placing shared libraries in standard locations).

There are two main ways to reference a file reliably when you don't know exactly where on the file system it will be (e.g. because you're going to install the software into different locations on different servers):

- Relative to the "document root", that is the path configured in the web server to be the location of the URL "/". This directory is available as the superglobal variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`; e.g. `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/getPublisher.php';`
- Relative to the current file, that is the file you are writing the PHP code in (regardless of how that file was accessed). This directory is available as the magic constant `__DIR__`; e.g. `require __DIR__ . '/../getPublisher.php';`

Notice in the second example I had to "climb up" from the current directory using `..` which means "parent directory"; you can climb as high as you like with this: `'/../../../../'` etc

Comment: There is a now a canonical for that topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory